# how to disable code signing in iOS Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-yosemite

I've been working on an iPhone project  with iOS 8.3, Xcode 6.3 having Os X Yosemite version 10.10.3 when I connect device to test App , getting error as below
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'
and
No matching provisioning profiles found:
so how do I disable codesiging and I want to test this on device.
Please Help!

Comment: You don't disable it. You read the docs and follow the steps needed to deploy an app to a real device.

Comment: I don't want to deploy an app. I just want to test app on device.

Comment: If you want to run the app in a device rather than a simulator, you must set the provisioning profiles .

Comment: That's what I meant by "deploy". You want to install the app on your device so you can test it. That requires setting up provisioning profiles.

Comment: can u send me link or any details information for provisiong profile?

Comment: @diptipatil : Go through Apple Docs : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html